# Correctness of the following derivation for $\Pr[ {X > \frac{2}{Y} \cap X > \frac{4}{Z}}]$?

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

Given that $X,Y,Z$ are exponential random variable with the corresponding parameters ${\lambda _1},{\lambda _2},{\lambda _3}$, does the following derivation  of this probability $A=\Pr[ {X > \frac{2}{Y} \cap X > \frac{4}{Z}}]$  correct ?

$\begin{gathered}
  \,\,\,\,\Pr \left[ {X > \frac{2}{Y} \cap X > \frac{4}{Z}} \right] \hfill \\
   = \Pr \left[ {X > \max \left[ {\frac{2}{Y},\frac{4}{Z}} \right]} \right] \hfill \\
   \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,= \Pr \left[ {X > \frac{2}{Y} \cap \frac{2}{Y} > \frac{4}{Z}} \right] + \Pr \left[ {X > \frac{4}{Z} \cap \frac{4}{Z} > \frac{2}{Y}} \right] \hfill \\
   \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,= \Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < \frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] + \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < \frac{4}{Z} < X} \right] \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

Where $\Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < \frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] = \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] - \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < \frac{4}{Z}} \right]$ (First point: Am I wrong here ?)

and $\Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < \frac{4}{Z} < X} \right] = \Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < X} \right] - \Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < \frac{2}{Y}} \right]$ (Second point: Am I wrong here ?)

So $A = \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] + \Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < X} \right] - \left( {\Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < \frac{4}{Z}} \right] + \Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < \frac{2}{Y}} \right]} \right) = \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] + \Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < X} \right] - 1$

Comment: Not correct. $Pr (A\cap B)=Pr (A) -Pr (B^{c})$ is not valid. The correct formula is $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A) -Pr(A \cap B^{c})$, so you cannot answer this question without using a triple integral.

Comment: So when does it go wrong, is it still correct up to this point 
$\Pr \left[ {X > \frac{2}{Y} \cap X > \frac{4}{Z}} \right] = \Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < \frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] + \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < \frac{4}{Z} < X} \right]$

Comment: When you ask 'Am I wrong here?' the first time you are indeed wrong.

Comment: Yes but before that  is it correct up to this point $\Pr \left[ {X > \frac{2}{Y} \cap X > \frac{4}{Z}} \right] = \Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < \frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] + \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < \frac{4}{Z} < X} \right]$

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: May I ask a stupid question, if $\Pr \left[ {1 < \frac{2}{Y} < 3} \right] = \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < 3} \right] - \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < 1} \right]$ then why $\Pr \left[ {\frac{4}{Z} < \frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] \ne \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < X} \right] - \Pr \left[ {\frac{2}{Y} < \frac{4}{Z}} \right]$ ?

Comment: $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)-Pr (B^{c})$ is correct if $B^{c} \subseteq A$ but not in general. Since $\frac 2 Y <1$ implies $\frac 2 Y <3$ the equation is valid in this case.

Comment: Thank you so so much